# Access to event command button event handlers in modules

Tags: vba, excel

I have a work book with about 20 different work sheets, each sheet structurally identical to each other. Now, I've added a command button in each of the sheets and I am calling a sub on each of the different sheets when the respective button is clicked. 
It works fine, but it's obviously terrible programming practice as I have 20 different sheets containing the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode <> True Then
    Call AddEntry
Else
    MsgBox "bla bla."
End If
End Sub
```

So my question, as an inexperienced VBA dev - what is the most elegant solution to call my sub on a button click? Ideally writing the code once in a module e.g.

Comment: You could just send `ActiveSheet` as an input parameter to `AddEntry` and perform your filter check in `AddEntry`. This would mean that in `CommandButton1_Click1` should just have `AddEntry` call. Although, as a teaser, there is a solution with **`class`** (which I am working on at the moment) which potentially can catch click of any Activex button and call `AddEntry` UDF

Comment: The first step towards an elegant solution is organizing the data better so you **don't** have 20 structurally identical sheets with 20 buttons.  If there is similar data across all the sheets, it's best kept on one worksheet, and then display whatever the user needs to see at that moment with the help of filters, perhaps a drop-down, maybe a listbox, or **a** button, etc...That many sheets are clunky, awkward, and hard to maintain, prone to issues... and, imo, *not* elegant.  As a rule of thumb, there should never be identical "anythings" in the programming/data world.

Comment: @Zac yeah, you're right about the filter check, I realized that when I copied the code on here. I am definitely curious about your class solution!

Comment: @ashleedawg true, but the decision to separate the sheets was definitely not coming from my side.

Answer (score 0):

instead of putting a command button in every sheet, just put only one button on the toolbar of excel